# How can I use an extra tom microphone when using the Scarlett 18I20?

Tags: recording, drums, microphones

I need to be able to use an extra tom microphone for my Scarlett 18I20 interface. The problem is that I already have microphones for inputs 1-4 (Bass Drum, Snare, Tom 1, Tom 2) and then I have 2 condenser microphones that require phantom power, which the interface only allows phantom on 1-4 or 5-8. I tried a XLR to 1/4" adapter but the audio signal is not coming across correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: You can turn phantom power on for all inputs 1-8 at the same time. Why are you not plugging tom 3 into input 5 or 7?

Answer (score 6):

A modern dynamic microphone with XLR plug will not mind phantom power getting switched on while it is plugged in.  You just should avoid (like with condenser microphones actually) to plug in the microphone while phantom power is already on.  The one microphone type you should really be careful about are ribbon microphones (and microphones that are old enough that they don't have a native XLR plug).  But ribbon microphones are not drum microphones anyway.

Comment: "ribbon microphones are not drum microphones " in the non-pro world maybe.  I've seen many ribbon microphones used for capturing drums in a pro setting.

Comment: I've used my ribbon as a drum overhead in my home studio many times.  Just make sure it's out of reach of an errant stick!